# Group Mind Understands Ecology

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a series; I seem to remember reading it no later than the early/mid ’90s.

An important plot point was a set of non humans—blue, I think—that operated in a group mind to understand the ecology of a world. They could decide whether it was safe to colonize the world, and could assist a colony to set up on such a world to know exactly what was safe to eat, to do, where were good places to locate the colony, and so on. There was a fair amount of mysticism attached to it, and somehow a human woman became part of one of these group minds.

The bluemanoids weren’t *inherently* a group mind; normally, they were as much individuals as humans - but some of them had the talent to join into these ecology-aware group minds. When they were joined, only one of them could interact with other people, as the “voice” of the group mind.

Comment: Just to clarify were the "non humans" still humanoid? Also were these novel length books, short stories, etc.?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yes, they were humanoid. I recall at least three novels, comprising one long story arc.

Comment: I'm at work and don't have time to type a full answer but this sounds a lot like the Xenogenesis Trilogy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenogenesis_Trilogy

Comment: @JDM - No, definitely not _Xenogenesis_, but thanks for something else to put onto my (increasingly long) to-read list.

Comment: I just realized... the other answer isn't marked as accepted, so we can't close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - is the sole criteria for "duplicate" an accepted answer that is the same? It seems to me that even though both questions have the same answer, they were asking about different plot elements, and someone asking about _this_ plot element wouldn't think to check a question focussing on _that_ plot element...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: For story-id, yes. The idea is that the answers get tied together in the database so you can correlate the different plot elements. I don't know how well it works in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In puttering around on the site, I found *my own answer* to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183797/science-fiction-book-series-with-name-similar-to-dunhau-chronicles/183805#183805), which is *unquestionably* the series I’m thinking of—the *Dushau Trilogy*, by Jacqueline Lichtenberg.

Comment: Oh, no worries at all. :) I do it all the time.